# How can I see SQL events (Application Insights) in the Diagnostic Tools window of Visual Studio 2015 in Console Application without using Azure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-application-insights, debug-diagnostic-tool

Is there any way to see Application Insights events (like SQL queries) in a Console application just like in a ASP.NET application?

I have installed Application Insights NuGets, configured the ApplicationInsights.config and I can see the events in the Output window but I cannot see them in the Diagnostic Tools window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work, *but*…

if you have an asp.net application that is configured to work, if you open up the .csproj file an look in it, somewhere near the top in a `PropertyGroup` section it should have something like

```
<ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/[some guid]/resourceGroups/[some name]/providers/microsoft.insights/components/[resource name]</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
```

paste that into a property group in the console app's .csproj, and reload the solution.

I *think* when you start debugging that's one of the things we look for, though we *might* have simplified some of this in VS2017 that used to work that way in VS2015.

in Vs2017 we might only be looking for project types we **know** we support in the diagnostic hub?

let me know if that doesn't work and I can go see if there's anything else that can force it to turn on.

Comment: Hi John! I couldn't find the <ApplicationInsightsResourceId> tag in the ASP.NET csproj file. Couldn't find it in other files neither :(